# Removing all seats except driver's + front passenger's one from Ford Galaxy Mk3 (2006)

Tags: ford, seat

Is it possible to completely remove all seats except driver's + front passenger's one from Ford Galaxy Mk3 (production started in 2006) to get a very flat loading floor? I was not able to find this information online - it seems to me you can only put the backrests down to achieve flat loading space, but not to remove the seats completely, which still gives you less space that without seats at all. It was possible in Mk2.

Comment: To fold second raw seats: Just pull the lever once to start folding. Pull second time to fold fully.

Answer (score 1):

I just found and [online resource](http://www.vybermiauto.cz/autoblok/clanek/test-volkswagen-sharan/ridicova-zona#kabina-a-kufr) in Czech ([translated to English by Google](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=cs&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=cs&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.vybermiauto.cz/autoblok/clanek/test-volkswagen-sharan/ridicova-zona#kabina-a-kufr)) about VW Sharan. It says: "Seats are just like the Ford Galaxy and S-MAX can not be removed from the car, but fold into the floor."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easy job third row seats, four torx bolts per seat through the slides.  Tape over the holes so the screws don't bottom out  on the structure below. Lots more useable space.